# My prefix grunts

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

> My prefix grunts,
>
> my infix can be found on a blunt.
>
> My suffix might be hard,
>
> but you'll find me in a yard.

**What am I?**

---

**Clarification**:

> The word "blunt" is used in reference to a marijuana cigarette. In this case, further knowledge of drugs or drug slang is not required. I would suggest focusing on the *cigarette* aspect of this word.

Comment: What does "on a blunt" mean? I have a possible answer, but I can't parse this line.

Comment: Blunt, meaning a marijuana cigarette.

Comment: darn it, I know absolutely nothing about drugs or smoking... Well, I'll try my best.

Comment: To your edit, technically knowledge of drug slang is required just to understand to word "blunt" as a noun! But not any more given that edit ... how meta.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know - ...you don't need to try drugs to get the puzzle. Just think on it :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe:

> Orchard

My prefix grunts,

> Orc - I don't think they say much.

my infix is found on a blunt.

> Char - You'll find it after the blunt is lit.

My suffix might be hard,

> It *is* hard!  That was a sneaky clue.

but you'll find me in a yard.

> Orchard - You might not think of them as being in a yard, but if you took the orchard away, you'd see that a yard is what you have left.  That's good enough for me!

Comment: You've got it! :)

Answer (score 6):

Are you a

> PIGSKIN

My prefix grunts,

> Pigs grunt.

my infix is found on a blunt.

> A 'skin' (rolling paper) is on a blunt.

My suffix might be hard,

> kin — family can be difficult.

but you'll find me in a yard.

> A pigskin (football) can often be found in a yard or field.

Alternatively,

> PIGGYBACK

But

> Pig still works, -ACK is a hard-sounding ending, and 'back' is found in a yard—a backyard! But I can't may the infix work. Gy? Iggy?

Comment: Incorrect, but very clever!

Answer (score 5):

Are you a

> Garden?

My prefix grunts,

> A gar, such as an alligator gar (which actually do make noises. They're actually pretty terrifying. They jump up out of the water).

my infix is found on a blunt.

> Gard, as in guard, because most blunt tools have some sort of guard, such as swords.

My suffix might be hard,

> A den can be hard to beat, especially a den of thieves.

but you'll find me in a yard.

> Gardens are commonly found in yards.

Comment: Clever, but not quite!

Answer (score 5):

Are you:

> HOGWEED

My prefix grunts,

> Hog(s) - Pigs, they grunt

my infix is found on a blunt.

> Weed is in a blunt

My suffix might be hard,

> ed (or ED) - Erectile Dysfunction is hard to recover from (LOL)

but you'll find me in a yard.

> Hogweeds are found in yards

Comment: Not correct, but hilarious nonetheless!

Comment: jwi, I'm pretty sure that your suffix implies _the opposite_ of hard!

Answer (score 5):

Are you a

> PIGEON?

*My prefix grunts,*

> PIGs grunt.

*my infix is found on a blunt.*

> I'm not familiar with drug slang (which the OP told me this is). Maybe GEO means something to do with marijuana?

*My suffix might be hard,*

> Hard ON?

*but you'll find me in a yard.*

> Pigeons in the yard!

Comment: Funny, but not quite. I've added some clarification :)